# missing Cats Functor[Future] instance

Tags: scala, future, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I am trying to use `OptionT` to combine methods returning `Future[Option[T]]` in a for-comprehension.

```
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.instances.future._

for {
  data <- OptionT(repo.getData(id))
  ... 
}
```

The compiler error I am getting:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter F cats.Functor[scala.concurrent.Future]
```

This [recent example](http://enear.github.io/2016/04/11/monad-transformers/) suggests that this is (was?) possible.

so do the docs in the [pull request for adding `OptionT`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/304/files#diff-90633fbe11dc38a796351af250106b42)

and the [cats `Functor` docs](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html)

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By importing [`cats.implicits._`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/implicits/package.scala) you are actually already importing `cats.syntax.AllSyntax` and `cats.instances.AllInstances`

Try using just those imports:

```scala
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
```

or (according to your needs):

```scala
import cats.data._
import cats.instances.future._
```

or more specifically:

```scala
import cats.data._
import cats.instances.future.catsStdInstancesForFuture
```

you may also need:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Note: of course you have to implicitly provide an actual `ExecutionContext` in a production environment.

Comment: removing import cats.instances.future._ and adding the ExecutionContext fixed this. Thank you, Federico.

Comment: I use `import cats.instances.future.catsStdInstancesForFuture` only, and remove all other related cats imports, can fix this error too

Answer (score 1):

Following imports work for me (also mentioned in [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43388906/432903)),

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.instances.future._ // or import cats.implicits._ 
                               // as implicits include FutureInstances

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Also, the important thing was the dependencies as I was using `org.typelevel:cats:0.9.0` along with `cats-core-1.1.0` which was causing `Symbol 'type cats.kernel.instances.EqInstances' is missing from the classpath.`

Had to remove older `cats-0.9.0` and use latest [`cats-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core) and [`cats-kernel`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-kernel_2.12).

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-kernel" % "1.2.0",

  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % Test
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like causes of this issue can be various; I just ran into this because I had two implicit `ExecutionContext`s available in scope, so cats was unable to select one to provide the `Functor[Future]`:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
// ^ first implicit ExecutionContext

class MyClass {
  def myMethod(e: EitherT[Future, _, _])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
    // Second implicit ExecutionContext
    e.flatMap(...) // <- Functor unavailable
  }
}
```

In my case I was able to resolve the issue by simply not passing `ec` into `myMethod`, though removing the global execution context would have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. `cats` actually has the instance.

The real issue is just the implicit `ExecutionContext` missing which you could just do the following

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

I realised this when I was trying to provide an instance for it.

```scala
    implicit val ev: Functor[Future] = new Functor[Future] {
      override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => B): Future[B] = fa.map(f)
    }
```

It's at this point the compiler will say the missing the `implicit ExecutionContext`